# Spring Batch: loading jobs dynamically at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-batch

**Is there any way to loading jobs dynamically at runtime, in Spring Batch?**

I have running application with Spring application-context

I want to load the following job dynamically at runtime:

```
<batch:job id="MyJob">
    <batch:description>MyJob Desc</batch:description>
    <batch:step id="step0_PromotionFetch" >
        <batch:tasklet ref="promotionFetch">
            <batch:transaction-attributes
                propagation="NEVER" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

My code:

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) configurableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();

GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext = new GenericApplicationContext();
    XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlBeanDefinitionReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(genericApplicationContext);

    xmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(configXMLFileName);

    BeanDefinition beanDefinition = xmlBeanDefinitionReader.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition("MyJob");

beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("MyJob", beanDefinition);
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#315': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.StateTransition] while setting bean property 'stateTransitions' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#315': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#315': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'step0_PromotionFetch' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'step0_PromotionFetch' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
```

is this the right way to do it?

Comment: <batch:step id="step0_PromotionFetch" >, step0_PromotionFetch is only an id

Comment: Is that the whole stacktrace? I think that error might have reasons outside of your job configuration...